# how to exclude specific characters and letter should be capitalized in text field

Tags: jquery

I have a text field `<input type="text" name="restrict">` which the values should be capital letters and numbers, excluding I, 1, 0 and O.

is it possible in jQuery to such thing? and how should I do it?

Comment: You can do this with `jquery validation`

Comment: Is this correct: Only letters and numbers should be allowed, 1 and 0 should not be allowed, I and O should be allowed but only as lowercase letters, all other letters should be capitalized. Let us know if that is right. This can definitely be done but we'll need to know more specifically what your validation rules are